# TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, runtime-error

I have done

```
npm install request
```

and my code is

```
const request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(response.statusCode);
});
```

but every time it is throwing a run time error

Comment: your code looks ok no issue with the code, I have tried and it's printing the correct statusCode

Comment: Ok, are you using a mobile network ??

Comment: In my case this happened due to a very dumb mistake on my part - I copied my Postman tests from another request and pasted it in Pre-req. tab instead of under the Tests tab!

Answer (score 4):

The `response` object might be `undefined` if no response was received so you have to check that it exists before accessing `statusCode`.

See the [example here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request):

```js
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
  console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
});
```

---

You might not have a response in case there is an error, so make sure to handle the error before trying to handle the response.

Comment: I just changed my code to this `const request = require('request'); request('https://www.google.com', function (err, response, body) { if (err) console.log(err); else console.log(body); });`

Comment: Is your problem fixed now ?

Comment: now the error is `Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND www.google.com`

Comment: no, it is not fixed. I have tried reinstalling node, but didn't work

Comment: That's another issue, not related with this one. It seems that you can't resolve the address, can you `ping www.google.com` ?

Comment: I can ping google from browser !! are you asking about this?

Answer (score -1):

it looks like that there is no response. I suggest you to log the error object as well and analyse the error message. Adjust also your code by checking if the `response` object is defined. Because the `undefined` means there is no `response` object:

```
const request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);  
  console.log('body:', body); 
});
```

Comment: `const request = require('request');
request('https://www.google.com', function (err, response, body) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        console.log(body);
});`

Comment: I have changed my code to this...I can see an error  saying `Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND www.google.com`